# Regular expression with exception in R (grep)

Tags: r, regex

Using `R` I would like to get from a vector of strings all strings that end with `_XXX` except those that have the word "Total" before `_XXX`.

```
mystringvector <- c("str1_XXX","str2_XXY","str3_XXX","Total_XXX")
grep("*_XXX",mystringvector,value=TRUE)
```

The results should return only `str1_XXX` and `str3_XXX`. But how can I include the exception for `Total_`.

Comment: `grep("(?<!Total)_XXX",mystringvector,value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)` `# [1] "str1_XXX" "str3_XXX"`

Comment: @Cath Maybe even `"(?<!^Total)_XXX"` with `perl=TRUE` if `SomeTotal_XXX` should be matched. Or just make sure there is a digit before `_`: `grep("\\d_XXX",mystringvector,value=TRUE)`

Comment: @Cath Ok, trimmed my comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew maybe but I really doubt that the real-life strings are `str1`, `str2` ;-)

Comment: @Cath That is why  I am not a fan of answering "oversimplified" questions. The examples should be real-life ones as the solution can be much better than a generic one

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can understand but to me it's more like if OP states the strings are "sometext_XXX", like "firststring_XXX", "secondstring_XXY", etc. it's different from having not reproducible example imo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lookahead, turning on `perl` option to precise you don't want `_XXX` to be preceded by `Total`:

```
grep("(?<!Total)_XXX", mystringvector, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE) 
# [1] "str1_XXX" "str3_XXX"
```

`?<` means "what is before must be" and `!` negates what's after it ("Total" here).