# Regex match with exception

Tags: r, regex, exception

I struggle to find a solution for following regex problem. I want to match from the beginning of the string everything with G06 but exclude G06Q. I guess its some kind of lookbehind?

`mystring <- c('G06', 'G06Q', 'G11C')`

What I want is

`[1] "G06"`

As a starter I tried following but it need obviously some additional part

`grep("^G06", mystring, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)` gives me

`[1] "G06"  "G06Q"`

Similar problem can be found here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078331/regular-expression-with-exception-in-r-grep) but I struggle to use it for my problem at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the end (`$`) of the string

```
grep("^G06$", mystring, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "G06"
```

Or use word boundary (`\\b`) to mark the end of the word

```
grep("^G06\\b", mystring, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "G06"
```

Comment: So simple, so good. Thank you!